# Google analytics data in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-analytics, admin

I,m working on an admin dashboard of a react web application and I want to use google analytics to track my web app data. I know how to do it in google analytics but actually, I want to get the data from google analytics to my website admin dashboard.

I've been looking for that in a lot of resources but I couldn't find a good information resource. Here I want to track the data using google analytics ad display it inside my website admin dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out, i think is what you need.

[Google Analytics Real Time Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3)

To summarize, everything is in your Google Console dashboard, with a API key you can access any data of (most) Google services.

See: [Google Console APIs](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/browse?q=analytics)